# Grouping size of selected tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I'm trying to get the total size of all tables that fit my criteria (latin column where the table collation is not latin, with text or varchar columns), however the sizes I'm getting are not anywhere near the actual sizes.

```
mysql> select t.table_schema,sum(data_length + index_length)/1024/1024/1024 
    from tables t 
    inner join columns c on t.table_schema=c.table_schema and t.table_name=c.table_name 
    where t.table_schema in ('db1','db2') 
        and  (c.collation_name like '%latin%' or c.character_set_name like '%latin%') 
        and  (c.column_type like 'varchar%' or c.column_type like 'text') 
        and  t.table_collation not like '%latin%' 
    group by t.table_schema;
+--------------+------------------------------------------------+
| table_schema | sum(data_length + index_length)/1024/1024/1024 |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------+
| db1       |                                  233.021102905273 |
| db2        |                                  93.742004394531 |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.54 sec)
```

Comment: Are they InnoDB tables? It doesn't update size information reliably.

Comment: I think the issue is with the WHERE clause because it has multiple columns and is adding all the columns instead of just the tables themselves.

Comment: Isn't that what you want? The total for all matching columns in all tables in each database?

Comment: I need the total size of the tables, but it is multiplying the columns per table so my results are larger than should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join with a subquery that just returns one row per table that matches the column constraints.

```
select t.table_schema,sum(data_length + index_length)/1024/1024/1024 
from tables t 
inner join (
    SELECT DISTINCT table_schema, table_name
    FROM columns  
    WHERE (collation_name like '%latin%' or character_set_name like '%latin%') 
    and (column_type like 'varchar%' or column_type like 'text') 
) c on t.table_schema=c.table_schema and t.table_name=c.table_name
where t.table_schema in ('db1','db2') 
    and  t.table_collation not like '%latin%' 
group by t.table_schema;
```

Comment: Thanks! Just had to add "c" in the inner join statement for it to work.

Comment: @user3299633 Or remove all the `c.` in the subquery, since they're not needed.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change your to be like

```
select t.table_schema,
sum(data_length) + sum(index_length)/1024/1024/1024 
from tables t 
inner join columns c 
on t.table_schema=c.table_schema 
and t.table_name=c.table_name 
where t.table_schema in ('db1','db2') 
and  (c.collation_name like '%latin%' or c.character_set_name like '%latin%') 
and  (c.column_type like 'varchar%' or c.column_type like 'text%') 
and  t.table_collation not like '%latin%' 
group by t.table_schema;
```

Comment: No, this provides the same incorrect query results.

Comment: @user3299633, see edit in answer. get the sum result first and then perform addition

Comment: Numbers don't appear correctly. Edit results appear in my original comment.